# Removing everything before a certain character in TCL

Tags: tcl

Input string : `4567-ABC`

I want to remove everything before "`-`" in the string so that Output will be ABC.

Output: `ABC`

Comment: I have the answer now, if someone has a better way let me know - [regsub {.*\-} $string ""] which is giving me output ABC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid regular expressions:

```
set string 4567-ABC

set output [lindex [split $string "-"] 1]
```

The `split` command takes a string and split characters as the arguments and returns a list.

Comment: Alternatively `lindex [split $string -] end` to get the last item, whatever index it is.

Answer (score 1):

[`string last`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M32) is useful here:

```
set string 4567-ABC
set idx [string last "-" $string]
set wanted [string range $string $idx+1 end]
```

Or without the intermediate variable

```
set wanted [string range $string [string last "-" $string]+1 end]
```

That even works if the original string does not contain any hyphens.